# Pymongo: None of DNS query names exist

Tags: python, mongodb, dns, pymongo

I am working on a project that was handed to me by a coworker. After pulling the repository I am unable to run, getting an error of

```
Exception has occurred: ConfigurationError
None of DNS query names exist: _mongodb._tcp.stage.xxxx.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.stage.xxxx.mongodb.net.xxxx.com., _mongodb._tcp.stage.xxxx.mongodb.net.hsd1.tx.comcast.net., _mongodb._tcp.stage.xxxx.mongodb.net.tx.comcast.net., _mongodb._tcp.stage.xxxx.mongodb.net.comcast.net.
```

What is weird is that this repo works perfectly fine for my coworker. He has the same python version, same dependencies/etc and no issues. Below is the requirements.txt

```
fastapi==0.65.2 
uvicorn==0.11.7
gunicorn==20.0.4
elastic-apm==5.8.0
pymongo[srv]==3.12.0
pydantic==1.7.4
singleton-decorator==1.0.0
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
oauthlib==3.2.0
python-multipart==0.0.5
cachetools==5.0.0
pytz==2022.1
python-dotenv==0.14.0
```

I am using Python 3.8.6, also tried using 3.9.10 but same issues.

This is exactly where I am erroring out.

```py
@singleton
class MongoDB:
    """MongoDB Class"""

       def __init__(self, config: MongoDbConfig):
            """Initial MongoDB Connection on collection level"""
            _uri = "mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@{host}/{db}?authSource=admin&replicaSet={replica_set}&readPreference=primary&connectTimeoutMS={timeout}&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1".format(
                username=config.username,
                password=config.password,
                host=config.host,
                db=config.db,
                replica_set=config.replicate_set,
                timeout=1000,
                maxPoolSize=config.max_pool,
            )
    
            self.client = MongoClient(_uri)
```

When I installed dnspython==2.2.1 my error reduced to

```
The DNS query name does not exist: _mongodb._tcp.stage.XXXX.mongodb.net.
```

My env variables and system variables line up exactly with my coworkers. We both work remote currently. I tried the google dns fix but it didn't seem to work. Any advice/tips on how I should solve this. I am completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

On the server where you run your app, in file `/etc/hosts` you can add the entry for the host where the mongodb should exist, like:

```
<IP_of_mongodb_server> _mongodb._tcp.stage.XXXX.mongodb.net
```

this is a mere workaround which will explicitly point _mongodb._tcp.stage.XXXX.mongodb.net to the IP you set in the file...

---

The best option is to have a public IP set as DNS entry at the mngodb.net website.. info can be found at the MongoDB Community. Example: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-connection-test-dns-name-does-not-exist/86048 or https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/dnshostnotfound-failed-to-look-up-service/109605

###### Update:

Since the above forum links seem to have been converted to Private links in the forum, here's another source for DNS troubleshooting: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#internet-service-provider-dns-blocks-connection-string

or maybe try to search for a Google) cached version of the above forum links: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zX8_TX_F_R8J:https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-connection-test-dns-name-does-not-exist/86048&hl=en&gl=bg&strip=1&vwsrc=0

Comment: Both of those are `403` deadlinks: "Oops! That page is private."

Comment: Answer Updated. But in general the act of setting public DNS is well documented all around Internet.. and not really MongoDB Specific.